# Magento 2 add query string to url when redirect to 404 page

Tags: magento2, query, https, querystring

Magento 2 custom module i am trying to add query param 
https://test.com/index?id=L_FRR3039-ODKLWG-GP4QPY

if i  give above format getting 404 page not found

https://test.com/index?id=L_FRR3039

it working fine
even 
https://test.com/index?id=L_FRR3039-ODKLWG_GP4QPY  this is also working

it is not taking

> -

multiple hyphens remaining all special characters taking
can anyone help me in this

Comment: Are you trying to get that query param in your custom controller?

Comment: yes, https://test.com/pawan?id=L_FRR3039-ODKLWG-GP4QPY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

Add this in your custom controller contructor.

```
public function __construct(Context $context,\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request){
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function getIddata()
    {
    // use 
        $this->request->getParams(); // all params
        return $this->request->getParam('id');
    }
```

You can get the param using this  `$this->getIddata();` in you controller file.

Comment: it helped for my issue

Comment: If this helped means please accept the answer. It'll helpful for others

Comment: accepted already